# Compile error when I declare constructor as explicit

Tags: c++

I write a smart pointer class. When I pass it to a vector, it shows some error message when compiling. But after I delete the explict declaration, it works. What's the error?

```
explicit shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<T>& sp)
```

> no matching function for call to `shared_ptr<int>::shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<int> &)`

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;




    template<class T>
    class shared_ptr {
    private:
      struct ptr {
        T* ptr;
        size_t count;
        void release() {
          if(-- count == 0) {
            delete ptr;
            delete this;
          }
        }
      };
    private:
      ptr* _ptr;
    public:
      explicit shared_ptr(T* p):
        _ptr(new ptr) {
        _ptr->ptr = p;
        _ptr->count = 1;
      }
      explicit shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<T>& sp):
      //explicit shared_ptr(const shared_ptr& sp):
        _ptr(sp._ptr) {
        ++ _ptr->count;
      }
      shared_ptr<T>& operator=(const shared_ptr<T>& sp) {
        _ptr->release();
        _ptr = sp._ptr;
        ++ _ptr->count;
        return *this;
      }

      shared_ptr<T>& operator=(T* p) {
        _ptr->release();
        _ptr = new ptr;
        _ptr->count = 1;
        _ptr->ptr = p;
      }

      T* get() {
           return _ptr->ptr;
      }

      T& operator*() {
        return *(_ptr->ptr);
      }

      T* operator->() {
          return _ptr->ptr;
      }


      ~shared_ptr() {
        _ptr->release();
      }


    };



    int main() {
        vector<shared_ptr<int> > vec;
        vec.push_back(shared_ptr<int>(new int(10)));
    }
```

Comment: How about showing some code?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: An `explicit` copy constructor is not something you'd usually want.

Comment: Which compiler do you have? It seems OK. At least on GCC

Comment: Your code compiles [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3FDYza$48)

Comment: Do not call your class `shared_ptr`.  Especially not then `using namespace std;`  While in theory nothing may go wrong, it is not a good idea.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this *should* be fine. `push_back` will just end up using placement `new` which performs direct-initialization. And that's fine with an explicit constructor.

Comment: i use gcc 4.4.6,and after i add another paramter -std=c++0x，the code pass compile, why it can't pass compiling by the default paramter.

Answer (score 1):

A constructor declared as `explicit` can only be used when *explicitly* invoking it. In this line:

```
vec.push_back(shared_ptr<int>(new int(10)));
```

You are passing a value to `vec` which, in a **C++03** implementation of the Standard Library, eventually gets *copied* into the vector, undergoing a copy-initialization such as:

```
_Tp __x_copy = __x;
```

The call to the copy constructor here is *implicit*, but your constructor is marked as `explicit`. Hence, the error.

Notice that the error **only** occurs with a C++03 compiler, or when compiling with the `-std=c++03` flag, because in C++11 the call to the `push_back()` function with an rvalue argument (like the temporary you are instantiating) would just end up creating the value in place with an *explicit* call to the copy constructor.

Therefore, I assume you are working with a C++03 compiler.

Normally, `explicit` constructors are constructors which take one argument *and* are not copy-constructors, in order to avoid awkward implicit conversions (actually, in C++11, `explicit` makes sense also for constructors which take more than one argument, because of copy-initialization through braced initializer lists).

Copy-constructors are usually *not* declared as `explicit`.